# What does a negative balance in a checking account mean?

Tags: banking

I just started using online banking, just to watch everything. I've notice that my current balance was -6.57?!

Does the -6.57 mean I've overdrafted or something?

Btw, it's a debt account..

Comment: what do you think it means?

Answer (score 1):

A negative balance in your Debit Account means you owe money to the bank - and yes, it probably means you have used more than what you had in your account ( overdraft ).

Comment: And unless you have overdraft protection, it probably means you'll pay a fee (around $35 or so).